# Get-InTuneManagedDevice deviceEnrollmentType filtering fail

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-intune

Looking at this page, I assumed I would use a numerical value for the query:
[deviceEnrollmentType enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/intune-shared-deviceenrollmenttype?view=graph-rest-1.0)

However the following does not work:

```
Get-IntuneManagedDevice -Filter "deviceEnrollmentType eq 5"
```

Since that fails with the following error:

> Get-DeviceManagement_ManagedDevices: 400 Bad Request
> {
> "error": {
> "code": "BadRequest",
> "message": "Invalid filter clause",
> "innerError": {
> "date": "2021-01-06T19:48:58",
> "request-id": "1acd4ba0-359f-457e-87f4-f99c0e947246",
> "client-request-id": "1acd4ba0-359f-457e-87f4-f99c0e947246"
> }
> }
> }

I tried referencing the string name this way:

```
Get-IntuneManagedDevice -Filter "deviceEnrollmentType eq 'windowsAzureADJoin'"
```

However that returns all devices regardless of what the deviceEnrollmentType is.

Answer (score 0):

I went with saving all Intune devices:

```
$intuneManageDevices = Get-IntuneManagedDevice
```

then sorting using `Where-Object`:

```
$windowsIntuneManagedDevices = $intuneManageDevices | Where-Object { $_.operatingSystem -eq "Windows" }

$windowsAndCompliantIntuneManagedDevices = $intuneManageDevices | Where-Object { $_.operatingSystem -eq "Windows" -and $_.complianceState -eq "compliant" }
```

I don't know what `deviceEnrollmentType -eq 5` means - when I look at the objects they list this property with values such as `"windowsAzureADJoin"` and `"userEnrollment"` - perhaps there is an MS document translating the numeric codes to the codes listed by `get-intunemangeddevice` or you can just work with the codes listed.